# iOS Protocol function call on viewDidLoad/setup

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a protocol that I can use on UIViewControllers that will do some setup work when the protocol is attached to a UIViewControler. I currently have the following code.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
}

extension MyProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func setup() {
        print("We have successfully setup this view controller")
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Other setup work here") // This line might or might not exist
        setup() // Goal is to remove this line, so I don't forget to add it across all my view controllers
    }
}
```

My question is, is there a way to remove the `setup()` call from within the `viewDidLoad` function? I think it'd be a lot safer to not have to call that function every time. If there is a view controller that forgets to add that one call, then the setup won't happen, and I want to try to prevent that.

There is a chance that the `viewDidLoad` function on the view controller that it is attached to will do other work (ex. in this example `print("Other setup work here")`), or there is a chance it won't do anything except for that `setup` call.

I'm also not completely opposed to moving that `setup` function call into a separate function within the view life cycle, but again those other functions in the view life cycle that get called might have other things that need to run as well, so I don't want to completely override them.

I have also considered using the `init` method somehow, but I think the problem with that is that the view won't have been loaded yet and therefor I can't do the proper setup work like changing a label's text and such.

Comment: You should swizzle `viewDidLoad` for that, or just create a base class like answered below

Comment: Swizzle `viewDidLoad`? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Check [this](http://iossolves.blogspot.com/2017/11/swift-4-method-swizzling-part-22.html) out.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Protocols don't do any work, they're just promises. What is the protocols role in this problem? Also, If the `setup()` method is crucial and needs to exist in every view controller, then just add it to every view controller. If you're afraid of forgetting to add it, I imagine you'll get an error of some sort when you do forget, which will remind you to add it. Every view controller needs a lot things that you don't forget to add, don't make this any different? Short answer: you likely want to explore subclassing your view controller.